# Getting user defined urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I would like to add to my app a way for users to create their own url.  So, what I mean by this, is that if a user wants to go to their webpage, they could go to http://www.projectdomain.com/JimmyJohn

In my model I have

```
class Person(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)  #username = JimmyJohn
    ....
```

Is the best way to do this by just adding a method that catches everything after `/` in `urls.py`?  Or is there a way to more tightly integrate my models with the `urls.py`?

Comment: The name of the class should be in singular. Therefore class Person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a url to your main urls.py accepting a first alphabetic argument (consider adding any other urls of your app above this, and validating usernames so your urls are not valid usernames):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... other fixed urls before
    url(r'^(\w+)/$', 'website.views.user_page', name='user_page'),
)
```

Then query for a User in your view matching the given username:

```
def user_page(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return render(...)
```